# How to retry sending users to the database if AWS Cognito trigger failed multiple times?

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-cognito

Basically what I want to do is store cognito users in a database, so I will add a "Post Confirmation Trigger" to do that, but unfortunately that trigger might fail in case the database is down.

According to the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-identity-pools-working-with-aws-lambda-triggers.html#important-lambda-considerations) Amazon Cognito retries the call and after 3 unsuccessful attempts, the function times out.

So my question is how to retry saving users again to the database in case all 3 invocations failed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could consider decoupling your architecture, in the case you have a unreliable or easily overloaded DB, by putting messages onto a queue (e.g. using SQS) and processing them with an AWS Lambda with a high retry limit and dead-letter queue setup.

One thing to consider with this type of setup though is that it is asynchronous, so if your application depends on the Post Confirmation trigger completing before it continues (i.e. in its standard synchronous setup), you may run into race conditions.

Comment: That's what I ended up doing, but I also made a `Pre sign-in` trigger to deny sign in requests if the user doesn't exist in the database already.